# Should "config.assets.compress = true" in development create bad css links?

Tags: asset-pipeline

In Rails 3.2.3, the html head tag contains links to all the styleheets in app/assets/stylesheets even though only the stylesheet_link_tag only referenced 'application' and all of the links are broken. What's wrong here:

When config/environments/development.rb has

> config.assets.compress = true

and app/assets/stylesheets/application.rb contains

```
 *= require_tree .
```

app/views/layouts/application.rb stylesheet section in the head tag contains only

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag( 'application' ) %>
```

then there is one link tag for every css file in app/assets/stylesheets. Each of the links is 404 except for the application.css and that one has all of the content that should be at each of the respective links.

Is this a Rails bug? Is it wrong to want to test compression in dev? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but in my development.rb i have this:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compile = true
```

These settings seem to work for me when i precompile in development. Also in application.rb i require all my assets as some of them don't work with just having the *= require_tree.

**My application.css**

```
*= require_self
*= require 'blueprint/screen'
*= require jquery.jgrowl
*= require jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css
*= require 'custom'
```

I had to leave out the *= require_tree bit, because it was causing unexpected issues. Restart server. Hope this provides some direction